# Run php script on a Firebase service

Tags: php, android, firebase, web-services

I need to send Firebase notifications from android device to another device. I know how to do it with java but it consider not a good practice to place private keys inside the android project in case someone hack it. So I need to do this through Firebase but I can't find any good reference to start with.

I am already using Firebase Storage and Firebase Real time database.

Which Firebase service should I use? I am familiar with PHP so should I use Firebase Hosting to upload there some php script?

Sorry if this is a newbie question.

Comment: you can use Firebase hosting but that doesn't have database in case you need

Comment: I don't need database. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 2):

Firebase does not offer any options for running PHP code for your app's backend.  You can use [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions), which runs nodejs.  Or if you must run PHP, you can use [Google App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/).

Comment: Can I use Firebase Hosting as Ronak commented?

Comment: Firebase Hosting does not run any code on the backend.  It just serves static content.